# Django dateutil attr value error when trying to runserver

Tags: python, django

When i try to run my server I get this error does anybody know what it means. Let me know if further code/info is needed thanks in advance.

```
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
  File "C:\Users\dariu\.conda\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 17, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import get_service_module_name
  File "C:\Users\dariu\.conda\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    import dateutil.parser
  File "C:\Users\dariu\.conda\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in `botocore` library version, which is not compatible with other libraries. Updating botocore will do the trick here like this -

```
pip install --upgrade botocore
```

Mostly updating your libraries should solve this issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If my answer solved your issue, then could you please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace line 158 `'value'` with `value`  and then run the server again.